# Live changes to Vue component if database table modified

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm so new to Vue JS. Just building a simple app with `Laravel & Vue JS` for practice.

I'm looking for something so that my `Vue` Component can load any changes which are are associated with `Vue` methods.

Template:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
        {{ user.name }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: {},
            form: new Form({
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                password_confirmation: ''
            })
        }
    },

    methods: {
        createUser() {
            this.form.post('api/user')
                .then(response => {
                    // Success
                    fire.$emit('afterCreate');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Error
                });
        },

        loadUsers() {
            axios.get('api/user').then(({ data }) => (this.users = data.data));
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.loadUsers();
        fire.$on('afterCreate', () => {
            this.loadUsers();
        });
    }
}
```

The above code works fine. E.g. When I add new `user` it load new `users`.

But I want to load `users` to Vue component, when the `users` table of database gets update. If anybody Insert/Update/Delete `user` from another computer, I should see the update from my computer.

Thats it!

Comment: Do you mean in realtime? Try to check Firebase realtime database

Comment: @SalmenBejaoui I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use websocket to make this, by broadcasting your events with socket.io and redis

follow this link : https://adnansabanovic.com/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io/

hope this help you